# malloc array of struct inside of struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc, realloc

I have project in school where in need to make a struct of AirportManager which holds the amount of airports and an array of Airport (another struct). I started writing the code but I having trouble with the malloc of the array of airports.
I attahced to code I write so far, the problem I have is that the values dont saved in the airportArray in the AirportManager.

```
//AirportManger Struct
typedef struct {
    Airport* airportArray;
    int airportAmount;
}AirportManager;

void initAirportManager(AirportManager* airportManager) 
{
    airportManager->airportAmount = 0;
    airportManager->airportArray = (AirportManager*)malloc(0);
}
void addAirport(AirportManager* airportManager)
{
    Airport airport;
    printf("Enter Airport Name: ");
    scanf("%s", airport.airportName);
    printf("Enter Airport Address: ");
    scanf("%s", airport.airportAddress);
    
    airportManager->airportAmount++;
    airportManager->airportArray = (Airport*)realloc(airportManager->airportArray, airportManager->airportAmount * sizeof(Airport));
    airportManager->airportArray = airport;

}

//Airport Struct
typedef struct {
    char airportName[MAX];
    char airportAddress[MAX];
}Airport;

//Main
AirportManager airportManager;
initAirportManager(airportManager);
addAirport(&airportManager);
```

Comment: `airportManager->airportArray = realloc(...);` directly followed by the (invalid) assignment `airportManager->airportArray = airport`. If the last assignment was valid, what do you think would happen? If you had e.g. `int a; a = 10; a = 20;` what would the value of `a` be? Why would it be different when it comes to pointers?

Comment: And considering that invalid assignment, and other problems, your code isn't a proper [mre] since it would not even build. Always test the [mre] you show us, to make sure it replicates the problem you ask about and don't have any unrelated problems.

Comment: Would you mind to [edit] your question and include some details _what troubles you have_, please? -- You need to check the result of `realloc()` in any case, but I don't think that this is the reason for a crash or whatever you get. -- As Someprogrammerdude already says, the assignment of a structure to a pointer to structures is wrong. Raise the warning level of your compiler to the maximum and correct your code until no more diagnostics are output. You need rethink what you want to assign to.

Answer (score 0):

The code has some issues. We shouln't:

- allocate zero bytes with `malloc(0)`
- assign twice to `airportManager->airportArray`
- use `scanf`

Here is the code modified. It uses `malloc` and `realloc` better, and `fgets` instead of `scanf`.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZ 512

typedef struct {
    char airportName[SIZ];
    char airportAddress[SIZ];
} Airport;

typedef struct {
    Airport* airportArray;
    int airportAmount;
} AirportManager;

// Call first on AirportManager
void initAirportManager(AirportManager* airportManager)
{
    airportManager->airportAmount = 0;
    airportManager->airportArray = NULL;
}

// Call last on AirportManager
void finalAirportManager(AirportManager* airportManager)
{
    airportManager->airportAmount = 0;
    if (airportManager->airportArray != NULL)
        free(airportManager->airportArray);
    airportManager->airportArray == NULL;
}

// Add an airport to the manager
void addAirportByNameAndAddress(AirportManager* airportManager, char *name, char *address)
{
    // Calculate the amount of memory needed
    size_t mem = (airportManager->airportAmount + 1) * sizeof(Airport);

    // Get the memory required
    Airport* newAirports = NULL;
    if (airportManager->airportArray == NULL)
        newAirports = (Airport*)malloc(mem);
    else
        newAirports = (Airport*)realloc(airportManager->airportArray, mem);
    if (newAirports == NULL)
    {
        // error: out of memory
        return;
    }

    // Copy the name and the address to new the new Airport
    Airport *current = newAirports + airportManager->airportAmount;
    memset(current->airportName, '\0', SIZ);
    strncpy(current->airportName, name, SIZ - 1);
    memset(current->airportAddress, '\0', SIZ);
    strncpy(current->airportAddress, address, SIZ - 1);

    // Update the manager
    airportManager->airportAmount++;
    airportManager->airportArray = newAirports;
}

void addAirport(AirportManager* airportManager)
{
    char name[SIZ] = { 0 };
    char address[SIZ] = { 0 };
    printf("Enter Airport Name: ");
    fgets(name, SIZ - 1, stdin);
    printf("Enter Airport Address: ");
    fgets(address, SIZ - 1, stdin);
    addAirportByNameAndAddress(airportManager, name, address);
}

void main() {
    AirportManager airportManager;
    initAirportManager(&airportManager);
    addAirport(&airportManager);
    finalAirportManager(&airportManager);
}
```

Comment: First if all I want to thank you for the help, I copied the code and run it without the finalAirportManager function in order to see that the values I enterd saved in the array, but in debug mode insted of the values it says "Error reading characters of string". Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: If the example solves your first question with ```malloc```, but you have another problem, then ask another question. Maybe include screenshots of the debug process.